# For a given random variable X, does there exists another random variable Y in different probability space, X and Y have the same distribution

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-distributions

X (known) is a random variable defined on probability space $(Ω_1 ,F_1 ,P_1 )$ , there exists a random variable Y in another probability space $(Ω_2 ,F_2 ,P_2)$  which has the same distribution as X. Is the proposition true? if true, how to prove?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, choose any nonempty set $E$ such that $E\cap\Omega_1=\varnothing$ and let $\Omega_2=\Omega_1\cup E$, $F_2=\{A\subseteq\Omega_2\mid A\cap\Omega_1\in F_1\}$ and $P_2(A)=P_1(A\cap\Omega_1)$ for every $A$ in $F_2$. Then *any* random variable $Y$ on $(\Omega_2,F_2)$ such that $Y=X$ on $\Omega_1$ has the same distribution as $X$.

Or, choose any probability space $(\Omega_3,F_3,P_3)$ and define $\Omega_2=\Omega_1\times\Omega_3$, $F_2=F_1\otimes F_3$, $P_2=P_1\otimes P_3$ The random variable $Y$ defined on $\Omega_2$ by $Y(\omega_1,\omega_3)=X(\omega_1)$ has the same distribution as $X$.

Or, consider $\Omega_2=\Omega_1^T$, $F_2=F_1^{\otimes T}$, $P_2=P_1^{\otimes T}$, for some nonempty set $T$. Then, for each $t$ in $T$, the random variable $Y_t$ defined on $\Omega_2$ by $Y_t(\omega)=X(\omega_t)$, for every $\omega=(\omega_s)_{s\in T}$, has the same distribution as $X$. Additionally, the sequence $(Y_t)_{t\in T}$ is independent.

**Edit:** The question of whether one can define a random variable with specified distribution on some specified probability space is different. The answer depends only on the distribution of $X$ and on $(Ω_2 ,F_2 ,P_2)$, not on $(Ω_1 ,F_1 ,P_1)$. Broadly speaking, the larger $(Ω_2 ,F_2 ,P_2)$ is, the more chance there is to succeed. For a specific distribution of $X$ and a specific $(Ω_2 ,F_2 ,P_2)$, the answer can be cumbersome (unless you explain which distribution and which probability space interest you). Quite generally though, $(Ω_2 ,F_2 ,P_2)=([0,1],\mathcal B([0,1]),\mathrm{Leb})$ allows to realize every distribution on $(\mathbb R,\mathcal B(\mathbb R))$.

Comment: Thanks! Your answer need to construct $Ω_2$. In my question, $Ω_1$ and $Ω_2$ are known and fixed.

Comment: That was unclear. The answer to *that* is that it depends on $\Omega_2$ and the distribution of $X$, not on $\Omega_1$, and that the larger $\Omega_2$ is the more chance to succeed one has.

Comment: I only want to know the existence of Y, not to know what is Y.

Comment: Please read: my answer deals with the *EXISTENCE* of Y.

Comment: In your answer, $Ω_2$ denpends on $Ω_1$ ($Ω_1 \subset Ω_2$)  , this is not what my need

Comment: No (except in the very first case). What "your need" is is more and more mysterious, I must say.